# Identifying when a Windows Xp Machine Crashed/Rebooted

Tags: windows-xp, crash, reboot, uptime

I have a Windows Xp SP3 box (doing the duty of a server) that is having uptime problems due to either power outages in the office, or some unexplained crashing. How can I find out the last time Windows booted up or crashed? The crashes only seem to occur every week or so.

I've tried going through the Event Viewer, but I can't seem to find anything that yells out ***Hey! I just rebooted*!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for System events -

> Source = EventLog
>
> ID = 6009 or 6005

This will show you when your box last started.

You should also look in the c:\Windows\MiniDump directory for any crash dumps.

Comment: Thats what I wanted!